# UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds is 480x320 but should be higher

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

I am wondering why UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds is 480 x 320, when the Screen Mode is 940 x 680.  How to set the right resolution as I want to target iPhone5.  I have set the simulator to be iPhone 5.

My screens are not looking like I want and I need to test on iPhone 5 resolution.

Where do I get the proper bounds or why are the bounds not what they should be?

Here is my appdelegate code

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // create a new window instance based on the screen size
            window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

            StartScreen homeScreen = new StartScreen();

            //add home screen to navgation controller
            // becomes the top most screen
            this.rootNavigationController = new UINavigationController();
            this.rootNavigationController.NavigationBarHidden = true;
            this.rootNavigationController.PushViewController(homeScreen, false);


            // set the root view controller on the window.  the nav controller witll handle the rest
            this.window.RootViewController = this.rootNavigationController;

            // If you have defined a view, add it here:
            // window.AddSubview (navigationController.View);

            // make the window visible
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

            return true;
        }
```

Comment: Screen bounds (in fact, all bounds on iOS) are given in points, not pixels, and your designs should also use points as the fundamental unit. The iPhone 5's display is 320x568 points.

Comment: Ok, so if that is all correct.  I need to determine why my image is showing up twice the size that is designed for in my xcode xib.  In the nib it is corrct size and is 600 pixels wide....  When running it shows up too big and strecthed beyond the size of the screen even though it is also set to Aspect Fit.  My assumption was the resolution of the screen was off.  But if it's correct, then what?

Comment: Also, if things are in points, then why does XCode say the With is 768 and height is 1,004 for my screen frame???

Comment: Ahh, I Think I just figured out my own problem :)

Comment: Sounds like a view with dimensions for iPad portrait mode.